# Effects of monomorphism restriction on type class constraints

Tags: haskell, types, recursion, polymorphism, monomorphism-restriction

This code breaks when a type declaration for `baz` is added:

```
baz (x:y:_) = x == y
baz [_] = baz []
baz [] = False
```

A common explanation (see [Why can't I declare the inferred type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259059/why-cant-i-declare-the-inferred-type/) for an example) is that it's because of polymorphic recursion.

But that explanation doesn't explain why the effect disappears with another polymorphically recursive example:

```
foo f (x:y:_) = f x y
foo f [_] = foo f []
foo f [] = False
```

It also doesn't explain why GHC thinks the recursion is monomorphic without type declaration.

Can the explanation of the example with `reads` in http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.5.5 be applied to my `baz` case?

I.e. adding a signature removes monomorphism restriction, and without the restriction an ambiguity of right-side [] appears, with an 'inherently ambigous' type of `forall a . Eq a => [a]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equations for `baz` are in one binding group, generalisation is done after the entire group has been typed. Without a type signature, that means `baz` is assumed to have a monotype, so the type of `[]` in the recursive call is given by that (look at ghc's -ddump-simpl output). With a type signature, the compiler is explicitly told that the function is polymorphic, so it can't assume the type of `[]` in the recursive call to be the same, hence it's ambiguous.

As John L said, in `foo`, the type is fixed by the occurrence of `f` - as long as `f` has a monotype. You can create the same ambiguity by giving `f` the same type as `(==)` (which requires `Rank2Types`),

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
foo :: Eq b => (forall a. Eq a => a -> a -> Bool) -> [b] -> Bool
foo f (x:y:_) = f x y
foo f[_] = foo f []
foo _ [] = False
```

That gives

```
Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraint:
  (Eq b0) arising from a use of `foo'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: foo f []
In an equation for `foo': foo f [_] = foo f []
```

Comment: The rank 2 version of `foo` is inspiring too, thank you! I start finally to grasp what shallow types are.

Comment: +1 Nice! Excuse me while I go play with my new understanding of Rank 2 types. ( http://ideone.com/RajuI )

Comment: I believe this answer is missing an important point of the question: the monomorphism restriction doesn't have anything to do with the declaration of `baz`. The only declarations in the declaration group of `baz` are *function* bindings and hence the monomorphism restriction doesn't trigger. The fact you mention is due to the Hindley-Milner type system: you first infer assuming monomorphic types and in the end generalize. If you provide a type signature the compiler uses that type for `baz` in the rhs and thus the ambiguity. But nothing to do with monomorphic restriction.

Answer (score 11):

Your second example isn't polymorphically recursive.  This is because the function `f` appears on both the LHS and RHS of the recursive definition.  Also consider the type of `foo`, `(a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`.  This fixes the list element type to be identical to the type of `f`'s arguments.  As a result, GHC can determine that the empty list on the RHS must have the same type as the input list.

I don't think that the `reads` example is applicable to the `baz` case, because GHC is able to compile `baz` with no type signature and the monomorphism restriction disabled.  Therefore I expect that GHC's type algorithm has some other mechanism by which it removes the ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for 'This fixes the list element type to be identical to the type of f's arguments'

Comment: @DanielFischer +100500 for 'generalisation is done after the entire group has been typed'. Can you put your comment as an answer?