# NoMonomorphismRestriction helps preserve sharing?

Tags: haskell, ghc, data-sharing, monomorphism-restriction

I was trying to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145503/why-does-adding-a-polymorphic-type-signature-degrade-performance) about polymorphism vs sharing when I stumbled upon this strange behaviour.

In GHCi, when I explicitly define a polymorphic constant, it does not get any sharing, which is understandable:

```
> let fib :: Num a => [a]; fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
> fib !! 30
1346269
(5.63 secs, 604992600 bytes)
```

On the other hand, if I try to achieve the same by omitting the type signature and disabling the monomorphism restriction, my constant suddenly gets shared!

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
> :t fib
fib :: Num a => [a]
> fib !! 50
20365011074
(0.00 secs, 2110136 bytes)
```

Why?!

Ugh... When compiled with optimisations, it is fast even with monomorphism restriction disabled.

Comment: An aside: Reasoning about performance in ghci is a little strange -- its a) about 30x slower than ghc itself, and b) any real world code will use optimizations, so lessons learned in ghci won't be that useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By giving explicit type signature, you prevent GHC from making certain assumptions about your code. I'll show an example (taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270548/effects-of-monomorphism-restriction-on-type-class-constraints)):

```
foo (x:y:_) = x == y
foo [_]     = foo []
foo []      = False
```

According to GHCi, the type of this function is `Eq a => [a] -> Bool`, as you'd expect. However, if you declare `foo` with this signature, you'll get "ambiguous type variable" error.

The reason why this function works only without a type signature is because of how typechecking works in GHC. When you omit a type signature, `foo` is assumed to have monotype `[a] -> Bool` for some fixed type `a`. Once you finish typing the binding group, you generalize the types. That's where you get the `forall a. ...`.

On the other hand, when you declare a polymorphic type signature, you explicitly state that `foo` is polymorphic (and thus the type of `[]` doesn't have to match the type of first argument) and boom, you get ambiguous type variable.

Now, knowing this, let's compare the core:

```
fib = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
-----
fib :: forall a. Num a => [a]
[GblId, Arity=1]
fib =
  \ (@ a) ($dNum :: Num a) ->
    letrec {
      fib1 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [a]
      [LclId]
      fib1 =
        break<3>()
        : @ a
          (fromInteger @ a $dNum (__integer 0))
          (break<2>()
           : @ a
             (fromInteger @ a $dNum (__integer 1))
             (break<1>()
              zipWith
                @ a @ a @ a (+ @ a $dNum) fib1 (break<0>() tail @ a fib1))); } in
    fib1
```

And for the second one:

```
fib :: Num a => [a]
fib = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
-----
Rec {
fib [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: forall a. Num a => [a]
[GblId, Arity=1]
fib =
  \ (@ a) ($dNum :: Num a) ->
    break<3>()
    : @ a
      (fromInteger @ a $dNum (__integer 0))
      (break<2>()
       : @ a
         (fromInteger @ a $dNum (__integer 1))
         (break<1>()
          zipWith
            @ a
            @ a
            @ a
            (+ @ a $dNum)
            (fib @ a $dNum)
            (break<0>() tail @ a (fib @ a $dNum))))
end Rec }
```

With explicit type signature, as with `foo` above, GHC has to treat `fib` as potentially polymorphically recursive value. We *could* pass some different `Num` dictionary to `fib` in `zipWith (+) fib ...` and at this point we would have to throw most of the list away, since different `Num` means different `(+)`. Of course, once you compile with optimizations, GHC notices that `Num` dictionary never changes during "recursive calls" and optimizes it away.

In the core above, you can see that GHC indeed gives `fib` a `Num` dictionary (named `$dNum`) again and again.

Because `fib` without type signature was assumed to be monomorphic before the generalization of entire binding group was finished, the `fib` subparts were given exactly the same type as the whole `fib`. Thanks to this, `fib` looks like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
fib :: forall a. Num a => [a]
fib = fib'
  where
    fib' :: [a]
    fib' = 0:1:zipWith (+) fib' (tail fib')
```

And because the type stays fixed, you can use just the one dictionary given at start.

Comment: Aha! That explains a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here you are using `fib` with the same type argument in both cases, and ghc is smart enough to see this and perform the sharing.

Now, if you used the function where it can be called with *different* type arguments, and defaulting led to one of those being very different than the other, then the lack of monomorphism restriction would bite you.

Consider using the term `x = 2 + 2` polymorphically in two contexts without the monomorphism restriction, where in one context you `show (div x 2)` and in another you use `show (x / 2)`, In one setting you get the `Integral` and `Show` constraints which causes you to default to `Integer`, in the other you get a `Fractional` and a `Show` constraint and that defaults you to `Double`, so the result of the computation isn't shared, as you are working with a polymorphic term applied to two distinct types. With the monomorphism restriction turned on, it tries to default one time for something both Integral and Fractional and fails.

Mind you its tricker to get all this to fire these days with let not generalizing, etc.